# Multiple successive declarations/definitions on same indentation level

Tags: c, clang-format

I'm trying to clean up my C codebase using clang-format (version 3.8.) on Ubuntu 14.04. As a requirement I need clang-format to maintain (or better enforce) the indentation of multiple successive declarations/definitions. For example:

```
void foo() 
{
    int        a;
    float      b;
    myLongType c;
}
```

After running clang-format I get the following output:

```
void foo() 
{
    int a;
    float b;
    myLongType c;
}
```

Is there an option that I'm not aware of to keep/enforce this formatting?

If this is not possible, is it possible to extend the functionality of clang-format locally (as it is with clang-tidy?) or do I have to open a feature request?

I know that this kind of formatting is mostly used in C code bases, and although the help message states "A tool to format **C**/C++/Java/...", all the options seem to be mainly targeted to C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just overread the correct option. From [Clang Format Options website](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> AlignConsecutiveDeclarations (bool):
>
> If true, aligns consecutive declarations.
>
> This will align the declaration names of consecutive lines. This will result in formattings like
>
> ```
> int         aaaa = 12;
> float       b = 23;
> std::string ccc = 23;
> ```

Comment: You are right, the second line should contain a valid `float` and the third a valid `string` to initialize the values. Although it is wrong in the clang docs as well. Maybe I should request a fix there first and then change my answer accordingly.